# Is 5 a prime element in the cyclotomic ring of integers?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Given a primitive 12-th root of unity, so its minimal polynomial is $$x^4-x^2+1$$ and hence the degree of its cyclotomic ring of integers is 4.

Recently I've learnt about quadratic field and ring of integers, $\mathbb{Z}[$$\sqrt{m}]$ where m congruent to mod 4 and how to find whether a number is a prime, irreducible by using norm. But as we know that there are degree 2.

How do I show that 5 is prime or not in the primitive 12-th cyclotomic ring of integers?

Thanks.

Comment: "m congruent... to what...mod 4"? What "there are degree 2"?

Comment: The quadratic extension $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ has twelfth roots of unity (its multiplicative group is cyclic of order 24), so $x^4-x^2+1$ factors modulo $5$. Therefore the prime ideal $5$ decomposes with $e=1$, $f=2$, $g=2$.

Comment: It isn't just $5$. Actually **no natural numbers are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{12}].$**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questions like this an indispensable tool is the Dedekind-Hasse criterion: If the ring of integers of a number field $K$ is $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ satisfies the monic polynomial $f(x)$, then the decomposition of a rational prime $p$ in $K$ is given by considering the decomposition of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. So, if $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$, then $p$ remains prime in $K$. In general if $f(x)\equiv\prod f_i(x)^{e_i} \pmod p$ where the $f_i(x)$ are distinct irreducible polynomials modulo $p$, then the prime $p\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ factors as the product of ideals $\prod (p,f_i(\alpha))^{e_i}$ in $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.

In your case, the ring of integers of the given cyclotomic field is $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ satisfies $x^4-x^2+1$.

From here, as Jyrki Lahtonen points out in the comments:
$$x^4-x^2+1\equiv (x^4-2x^2+1)-4x^2=(x^2-1)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2-1-2x)(x^2-1+2x)\pmod 5,$$

so that $f$ is not irreducible $\pmod 5$ and so $5$ does not remain prime in $Z[\alpha]$.

---

My original incorrect argument: Looking at this modulo $5$, and making the substitution $y=x^2$, we are looking at $$y^2-y+1 \pmod 5 $$ which has no roots and hence is irreducible. Thus so is $x^4-x^2+1$ and so the prime $5$ remains prime in the given field extension.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen! Do you mind if I add that to my answer and credit you or would you like to make that your own answer. I'd be happy with either :)

Comment: Go ahead, and fix the answer. I need to catch some shut-eye, and your post is otherwise correct and to the point. I will upvote the corrected version in the morning :-)

Comment: Ah, I see.. Thanks for your advice. Can I ask one more question? I don't fully understand about the lectures, so is it the same or relevant to the theorem, says p is a prime in Z then (p) is prime iff p is a prime in  Z[α]

Comment: If $(p)$ is a prime ideal , $p|ab$ if and only if $ab=pk$ if and only if  $ab\in (p) $ if and only if either $a$ or $b$ is in $(p)$. i.e. $p|a$ or $p|b$. and this shows that $p$ is a prime element. This shows both directions at once, I think.

Answer (score 1):

More simply: $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{12}]$ contains $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_4]=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and $5=(2+i)(2-i)$.

Comment: Very nice trick!